# .Net 4.5.1 Automatic binding redirect

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, .net-4.5

Based on the following msdn link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx
we get the information that

> Starting with Visual Studio 2013, new desktop apps that target the
>   .NET Framework 4.5.1 use automatic binding redirection. This means
>   that if two components reference different versions of the same
>   strong-named assembly, the runtime automatically adds a binding
>   redirection to the newer version of the assembly in the output app
>   configuration (app.config) file. This redirection overrides the
>   assembly unification that might otherwise take place. The source
>   app.config file is not modified

Now I am trying this scenario using a simple console APP and an AfterBuild event to send the assembly to GAC. When I use the installer to install the assembly it works on upgrading library (which is being consumed) there is a new folder in C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Assembly but the application keeps on using previos version instead of the one most resently deployed i.e. if first version was 1.0.0 and the new version was 2.0.0 the app continues to use version 1.0.0 even though I have set true in .csproj file and .Net version is v 4.5.1
I am not able to move forward on this any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is completely the point of the GAC.  It always supplies the version you asked for when you built the project, never the "last one deployed".  A very strong DLL Hell counter-measure.  If you want to use 2.0 then you **must** update the reference assembly.  Go easy with the GAC, it is very useful on the user's machine but not on yours.

Comment: @HansPassant So are publisher policy the only option or as pointed in the MSDN article; shouldn't automatic binding redirection take care of such a thing?

Comment: Using proper reference assemblies is the correct option.  Automatic binding redir is a band-aid for programmers that have large solutions with projects they didn't write that reference different versions of an assembly.  Which is a very ugly problem that you never want to intentionally create.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah seems so but I am already in as one the client is asking to migrate an old .net 2.0 project where they have heavely used publisher policies and binding redirects

Comment: Well, good opportunity to get rid of all that cruft.  Surely the reason they asked for this.